# How does Keras compute the loss among multiple outputs with the same loss function? Does it sum them up or make an average?

Tags: r, keras

I'm using Keras in R, its documentation specifies:

> If the model has multiple outputs, you can use a different loss on each output by passing a dictionary or a list of losses. The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses.

In the case I have multiple outputs but with the same loss function applied, Keras still sums them or does it make another transformation such as average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always the sum of the individual loss terms, but its a weighted sum, and there is one weight associated to each loss, so you can implement average by setting the right weights.

Weighting is needed because each task (output) might have different ranges and importances for the final loss that is being optimized.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys, what are the weights by default? Because I haven't specified weights in my models

Comment: @N.M. 1.0 by default for each loss.

Answer (score 1):

Follow @Matias Valdenegro answer, you can configure the loss_weight for each loss term in Keras model.compile(loss_weights={'output_name': loss_weight})

Ex: you have your loss function: `L = λ1*L1 + λ2*L2 + λ3*L3`
Then in keras you will configure:
`model.compile(loss_weights={'output1_name': λ1, 'output2_name': λ2,'output2_name': λ3})`